# Setting Active Cell for excel generated by PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am using **PHPSpreadsheet**

I am using **freezePane('A9')** in every excel generated by our web application.

At end, I am also adding **setSelectedCell('A9');**.

But when I open excel file it gets open with **"A10"** as the active cell. And also **"A9"** is scrolled down. So one has to scroll up to see row "9".

Check here an image of the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a little like your issue, https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/389

Their response of a sorts of fix is this:

> can be corrected by explicitly providing 'topLeftCell' argument:
>
> `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2','A2');`